# Issue Converting .html.erb to .html.haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

So I'm converting all my html.erb files to html.haml because haml is beautiful and clean. I used [this tutorial](http://screencasts.org/episodes/using-haml-with-rails-3) to convert all the files at once rather than one at a time. But I've come across an error that I'm not sure how to get it to work properly.

`#main.column{:class => "has_sidebar" if content_for?(:sidebar)}`

in html.erb it would be:

```
<div id="main" class="column has_sidebar"> #if :sidebar exists 
<div id="main" class="column"> #if :sidebar does not exists
```

So how would I go about getting this to work? thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the haml code like this :-

```
-if content_for?(:sidebar)
  #main.column.has_sidebar
```

Comment: I only want the class ```.has_sidebar``` to be added to the ```#main.column``` element if there's ```content_for?(:sidebar)```

Comment: That'll work for now. I was trying to do it in one line so that I don't have 3 extra lines of code. Thanks!